# Group rows while excluding null values on specific column and aggregating another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

| CUSTOMER_ID | ALIAS_ID | ULTIMATE_NAME | MODEL_SUB_TYPE | OLD_PD | OLD_EXP | OLD_ECAP | RATING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 123 | Company A | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 1 | BB+ |
| Client A | 123 | Company A | CI_POL_KN | 0.5 | 1 | 1 | null |
| Client A | 456 | Company B | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 3 | BB+ |
| Client A | 456 | Company B | CI_POL_KN | 0.5 | 1 | 3 | null |

What I need my query to do is to ignore the values in `OLD_PD`, `OLD_EXP` and `RATING` columns when `MODEL_SUB_TYPE =  Sub_type B`, and aggregate (sum) the `OLD_ECAP` column regardless of `MODEL_SUB_TYPE`.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    ALIAS_ID,
    SUBSTR(ULTIMATE_NAME, 0, 70) as ULTIMATE_NAME,
    MODEL_SUB_TYPE,
    CASE
        WHEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_COM_%' THEN ULTIMATE_POD
    END AS OLD_PD,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_COM_%' THEN CREDIT_LIMIT_NET_EXPOSURE
        END
    ) AS OLD_EXP,
    SUM(EC_CONSUMPTION_ND) AS OLD_ECAP,
    ULTIMATE_RATING AS RATING
FROM
    CALC6619.SO_REPORTING -- OLD QUARTER --
WHERE
    MODEL_TYPE LIKE 'IR'
    AND MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_%'
    AND CUSTOMER_ID = '09781C1 01' -- Customer ID
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    ALIAS_ID,
    ULTIMATE_NAME,
    MODEL_SUB_TYPE,
    ULTIMATE_POD,
    ULTIMATE_RATING
```

What I **want** is my **query to return** a table like this (based on table above):

| CUSTOMER_ID | ALIAS_ID | ULTIMATE_NAME | MODEL_SUB_TYPE | OLD_PD | OLD_EXP | OLD_ECAP | RATING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 123 | Company A | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 2 | BB+ |
| Client A | 456 | Company B | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 6 | BB+ |

But it's actually returning a table like the first one, but with null values where it's supposed to be, but not grouping the rows per company ID, like so:

| CUSTOMER_ID | ALIAS_ID | ULTIMATE_NAME | MODEL_SUB_TYPE | OLD_PD | OLD_EXP | OLD_ECAP | RATING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 123 | Company A | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 1 | BB+ |
| Client A | 123 | Company A | CI_POL_KN | null | null | 1 | null |
| Client A | 456 | Company B | CI_COM_KN | 1 | 1 | 3 | BB+ |
| Client A | 456 | Company B | CI_POL_KN | null | null | 3 | null |

Comment: Your query and sample data is not matching and not easy to map with each other. Please provide the exact query that you have used to fetch the data shown here as sample data

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated the query I have to match exactly the table above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the columns from `group by` and do some changes in `SELECT` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    ALIAS_ID,
    SUBSTR(ULTIMATE_NAME, 0, 70) as ULTIMATE_NAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_COM_%' THEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE END) AS MODEL_SUB_TYPE,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_COM_%' THEN ULTIMATE_POD
    END) AS OLD_PD,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_COM_%' THEN CREDIT_LIMIT_NET_EXPOSURE
        END
    ) AS OLD_EXP,
    SUM(EC_CONSUMPTION_ND) AS OLD_ECAP,
    MAX(ULTIMATE_RATING) AS RATING
FROM
    CALC6619.SO_REPORTING -- OLD QUARTER --
WHERE
    MODEL_TYPE LIKE 'IR'
    AND MODEL_SUB_TYPE LIKE 'CI_%'
    AND CUSTOMER_ID = '09781C1 01' -- Customer ID
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    ALIAS_ID,
    SUBSTR(ULTIMATE_NAME, 0, 70)
```

Comment: That worked! I didn't know I could use max for strings also. Thanks a lot!!